# Word VBA command to determine if found character is at beginning of end of line

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro that will search for a single character and perform a specific action based on whether or not the character is at the end (do nothing) or beginning (do something) of a line.

In my quest to find how to do this, I've seen plenty of documentation for determining if the text is at the beginning or end of a document or page or paragraph or on a specific line, or its position in a cell, but nothing about the columnar (I assume)position relative to a line of text.

Does anyone know if such an animal exists?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not add words such as "SOLVED" to question titles.

Comment: Hi, YowE3K - Unlike other messages on this site, I do not see any option to vote on the best answer nor "accept" an answer as a solution to my question, as explained in the link that Arul provided below. What is wrong this this picture?

Comment: There should be a greyed out check mark next to Arul's answer (to the left of it I believe, underneath the current vote count).  "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in". If you don't see the check mark next to the answer, it might be an unreported bug, so you may need to raise a bug report on meta.stackoverflow.com.  (You can also upvote the answer(s) that you believe are helpful by clicking the arrow above the vote count(s).)

Comment: The only option I have next to Arul's comment is to mark his answer as "useful" (not "accepted"), and I've never seen an upvote option on any of my post. So confused!

Comment: You should see a check mark underneath the score - a bit like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITDNa.jpg).  If you are not seeing that, please raise a question on meta.stackoverflow.com asking why you aren't seeing it.  (Include a screen shot of the bit to the left of the answer, just so people don't think you are just imagining it isn't there.)

Comment: Actually, you have accepted some answers in the past, so you must know what it looks like.  So definitely raise a bug report if it isn't there.

Comment: Oh, my goodness! That check mark has been there the whole time, but since it was gray, I just didn't hover my mouse over it to see the tool tip text and assumed it wasn't an option. I'm so used to interpreting grayed-out icons and text as being "unavailable" that I just didn't even bother to check it. This old dog (64!) is so happy to have learned a new trick. Thanks so much!  ~No Longer Clueless in Missouri :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterColumnNumber)` will give you the position of first character in the selected text relative to the line. Is this what you are searching for?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, Arul. Thanks much!

Comment: Instead of adding [SOLVED] to your question every time, you can just mark the answer as "accepted". Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers